# How do I fix the cookies “SameSite“ attribute error in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm setting cookies in javascript, but getting this error in firefox:

```
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute
```

```
var cookieData = { cookieName: $(this).attr('cookieName') };
setCookie('testCookie', cookieData, 10);

function setCookie(cname,value,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + JSON.stringify(value) + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Do I need to add SameSite=None somewhere?

Comment: Well without seeing what `cookieData` is it may be hard for anybody to help.

Comment: @Pointy, I shoudlve just put a string in there to avoid confusion - anyway, i have updated the question with the cookieData. the cookie is set after someone clicks a button (with attr 'cookieName')

Comment: Explanation of the error message: https://www.tinstar.co.uk/studio-blog/some-cookies-are-misusing-the-recommended-samesite-attribute-how-to-fix/ How to add the attribute, when setting cookies via JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie, [ctrl]+[f], “samesite”